# Unable to access UEFI settings on Lenovo

Tags: boot, grub, uefi, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo G580 on which I installed Windows 8 and several Linux distros which have messed with my booting. The last I used was boot-repair tool.
I have an EFI partition on sda2. The Grub load and I can boot to windows or Linux Mint or Mageia.

It seems now I cannot access UEFI by my regular F2 key. On searching around I found this thread:
[BIOS Setup Menu is not Accessible](http://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-BIOS-SETUP-MENU-IS-NOT-ACCESSIBLE)
I want to know how can I get back my UEFI settings menu? From what I understand, I have messed up my Lenonvo's NVRAM. The tool efibootmgr shows no entries at all.Is there a safe way to restore it? I can boot to Linux but any change I make may render my laptop bricked as there are no other boot option.

Comment: I am sure this is not.I confirmed F2 is my key and I have been doing this for ages.It is not a problem of simple quick booting.Is there a way to access firmware after grub loads?

Comment: at one point when I had installed refind bootmanager, the BIOS boot options had loaded and they showed only one enty viz. Refind. now that is gone,which leads me to believe I have overwritten my NVRAM.Its not a problem of missing a key.somebody on IRC suggested to check fwsetup command.

Comment: I checked.Its a command to boot to firmware from Grub.Doesnt seem to work though.Do you suggest flashing my BIOS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15185/discussion-between-marti-and-ramhound).

Comment: Yeah.Its the same, boots to GRUB.Yeah I mean to access those settings where I can change boot media priority etc UEFI

Comment: @Ramhound FYI, the "firmware setup" menu in grub works by running `fwsetup`. So if `fwsetup` at the grub prompt doesn't work, then its doubtful the menu item (were it there) would either.

Comment: I have tried restarting from windows(which should nullify fastboot if it was present) still the same.